# How to post multiple photos on facebook via javascript api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using this code for share photo on facebook 
its working fine 
but i want share multiple photos on one click with js api

```
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; 
var postMSG = "Hello ...";  
var filename = $('#photo1').val(); 
var url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token="+accessToken+"&message="+postMSG;
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
    message:postMSG,
    url:filename        
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error)
        {
           alert(response.error);
           console.log(response);
           alert(response);
        }
        else
        {  
           alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API does not support multiple photo upload in one go.

You have to loop through your images, and call `\POST /photos`.

```
foreach(image)
{
    \POST /photos
}
```